# Numero predeterminado de filas DATABLES

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Tengo una Datables con la siguiente configuracion y todo funciona bien :

```
 $('.lista_actividades').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../../php/gestion_tareas/cargar_actividades_planificacion.php",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "aaSorting": []
    },
    buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
],
    "columns": [
        { "data": "actividad" },
        { "data": "opciones" }
    ]
} );
```

Pero me muestra muchos registros a pesar de que esta paginado, como hago para que me muestre de 5 en 5 filas ?

Answer (score 0):

Haz intentado con

```
$('.lista_actividades').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

Siendo 50 el numero de rows a mostrar.

Saludos cordiales,

Comment: Me siguen saliendo de 10 en 10

Comment: Estas cargando las librerias de Datatable? https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js